# set fastMathEnabled for precise calculation in swift

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

Since I need not optimizations for floating-point arithmetic in my calculation how may I set fastMathEnabled to false in swift?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to apply to all shaders that are compiled by Xcode and included in the default library, you can add the option *-fno-fast-math* to the MTL_COMPILER_FLAGS (Other Metal Compiler Flags) setting in the Xcode build settings. Source: [Apple Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf).

If you are compiling the shaders at runtime, you pass the option to the [MTLDevice makeLibrary function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433431-makelibrary):

```
let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let options = MTLCompileOptions()
options.fastMathEnabled = false
try device.makeLibrary(source: source, options: options)
```

where `source` is the string containing the shader source code you want to compile.

Comment: I am getting an compilation error "expected unqualified-id
source".Any suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like a Metal shader compilation error rather than a Swift compilation error?  If so, please open a separate question and include there the shader code that doesn't compile.